# Build eclipse deployable feature in cli or update site in cli

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, m2eclipse, update-site

I have below 3 packages

**eclipse plugin,
eclipse feature and
update site**

Now I have to build eclipse feature in cli as same as right click over feature -> Deployable feature -> archive.zip . Tried with maven tycho but it is building jar not the archive file.

Otherwise I have to build update site in cli as same as open site.xml -> Build all. Tried with p2 publisher but it is not creating contents.jar, artifact,jar, plugin and feature folders.

Please help me to automate the build in cli.

Regards,
Sunil

Comment: Tycho is the way to go. [This tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html) ([example](https://github.com/vogellacompany/tycho-example)) works for me. Show a minimal example to reproduce your issue, so that one can help you.

Comment: @howlger, Thank you very much for your response. Example project in git doesn't build package. We have only root pom in the project and no pom files inside plugin and feature. Will it create package with only root pom??

Comment: Yes, that's called POM-less: with [`.mvn/extensions.xml`](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/master/.mvn/extensions.xml) no `pom.xml` files are required per plugin/feature folder. Make sure to run Maven 3.6.3 and Tycho 2.1 with Java 11 or higher.